# Why CheckBox always returns False

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use `chbname.Checked` in code behind like this:

```
Boolean chbchecked;
chbchecked = chbDefault.Checked;
```

But it always returns `false`.

Please help

Comment: Did you set it to `false` in `Page_load` ?

Comment: Just put a condition in Page_Load. Postback check the condition of the page will then refresh the gridview and dropdownlist.

Comment: You may hard-coded it to `false` somewhere.

Comment: You aren't providing enough information, like where are you checking it and have you checked the box before the check occurs?

Answer (score 0):

set AutoPostBack = "True" for the checkbox and try

```
  <asp:CheckBox id="chbname" runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="True"/>
```

Comment: after click the checkbox page is postback and after postback checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Is it worth to set `AutoPostBack` to true to resolve the prob?